# Alarm not displaying a notification or playing a sound, even though it is set

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

I'm currently working on an Android app that sets an alarm to trigger at a specific time. I've implemented the code to set the alarm, and it seems to get set without any errors, which can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5JzZ.png) and in the alarm tab.

However, the alarm doesn't trigger at the designated time, and as a result, there's no notification, sound, or any other action referenced in [setAlarmClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) played (apart from the pending intent, which is being started correctly).

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using to set the alarm:

```
val intent = Intent(context, AlarmClockReceiver::class.java)

val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, reqCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

val alarmManager: AlarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager


val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
    timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, desiredHour)
    set(Calendar.MINUTE, desiredMinute)
val calendarMillis = calendar.timeInMillis
alarmManager.setAlarmClock(AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendarMillis, pendingIntent), pendingIntent)
```

I have checked if I can set [exact Alarms](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#canScheduleExactAlarms()) and I've defined and requested the following permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like setAlarmClock doesn't  implement default behavior with notifications and sound. I just think the documentation could express it a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I have check list for you)

1. add `set(Calendar.SECONDS, 0)` because it can be in range of 0..59 when you set alarm.
2. change your `pendingIntent` with
   `val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, reqCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)`

P.S you can check my project with alarms https://github.com/hicosmonaut/hourly/tree/master nothing special, app alarms every hour like Casio watch hourly alarm. Maybe you find some useful for you there are PendingIntent, AlarmClock etc

Comment: Firstly, thank you for answering. It sadly didn't fix the issue, but I will take inspiration from your project.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to update permissions - SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM & USE_EXACT_ALARM don't work together. One is up to SDK32 and the other on 33+

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" android:maxSdkVersion="32" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />`

Then you should check multiple battery saving features that might block alarms in your app.

- is app ignoring battery optimizations?
- is schedule exact alarms permission granted (maybe not needed if you use setAlarmClock() instead of setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() )?
- is app hibernation restriction disabled?

Unfortunately playing with exact alarms in Android is painful.